# Set windows scheduler to schedule open a website, webpage or the bookmark

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have a bookmark: `C:\inetpub\services\Full Scan\full scan.url`
or a link: `10.237.49.250:8080/scanner/run.aspx?FULLSCAN=ON`

how can I schedule either of them to open in IE or Chrome?

Comment: Not sure how this is a duplicate, if my question was added here couple of months earlier that the alleged 'original'... time travel perhaps...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Specify the Action as start a program and specify the location of IE or chrome, for IE it is `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

Enter the URL is the arguments box and click ok.

[image]

and for Google Chrome

[image]

Comment: have you tried your method?

Comment: yep, I have tried it

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial of how to use the windows scheduler application in windows XP

http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm

this is how to use windows scheduler in Windows 7

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task

this is what the task needs to be it will run in the default browser without quotes

"http://10.237.49.250:8080/scanner/run.aspx?FULLSCAN=ON"

Comment: Have you tried your method?

Comment: Nope seem pretty straight forward