# Schedule to open website

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to open a website at regular intervals per day, i.e., the browser should open and automatically navigate towards a pre-set URL.

I looked at options like scheduling to open browser, but I can't figure out how to open it with a default URL. (No I do not want to make this my start page)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: O.o Why?  To me I would get annoyed at the self created pop-ups.

Comment: I understand it gives off that sense. But the reason is, I need to be filling out certain webform once perday and I keep forgetting. Besides, it's a curiosity whether such a thing can be done.

Comment: Understandable.  I just wasn't able to think of a use case that made sense to use this functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set windows scheduler to open a webpage or the bookmark](http://superuser.com/questions/447368/set-windows-scheduler-to-open-a-webpage-or-the-bookmark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a batch script that starts the browser with the desired URL (for example "c:\program files\internet exploder\iexplore.exe 'http://www.yahoo.com'" would be valid for internet explorer to open and automatically navigate to www.yahoo.com).
You can then schedule that batch file to be run when you want it to.

Answer (score 13):

1. Use Task Scheduler
2. Make it launch something like `iexplore.exe "http://www.microsoft.com/windows"` (replace with your browser's executable, such as `firefox.exe` etc.)

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

While, basically, launching Internet Explorer (or other browser executable) is OK, a better solution would be launching the *default* browser associated with handling URLs.

So you can create the following scheduler action:

```
Action: Start a program
Program: cmd.exe
Add arguments: /c start http://example.com
```