# Schedule image pop-up using task scheduler

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, tasks

I would like to know how to schedule a pop-up image every 1 hour on Windows 8.1. I tried to make a batch containing file name and file type and open the batch through Command Prompt by setting a CMD command in windows task scheduler. It didn't work. I don't think I know how to do this and if it's possible...
Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Dont downvote please (im not the asker) i think its a nice question. ive learned something.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. You need to simply assign a program to open the image(Picasa viewer for example) and then specify the location of the image.

Comment: Yeah yeah ive found it too :D i was looking for a way to get it work with Windows photo viewer .. it uses dllhost.exe and I dont know how to get it work. Also check this out http://superuser.com/questions/447368/set-windows-scheduler-to-open-a-webpage-or-the-bookmark

Comment: @TechLife have you upvoted the question?

Comment: @TobyAllen yeah, why?

Answer (score 5):

Found it. If you want to open the image file using windows photo viewer (Ive done this in win7 actually, should work on 8 too) when you are in task scheduler, hit `Create a basic task` and give a name and time and in the Action part hit `Start a program` and in the next step in the `Program/script` part put this:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe
```

and in the `Add arguments (optional)` paste the text below and remember to substitute `__PATHTOFILE__` with full path of the image file like C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\file.jpg without any quotes:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen __PATHTOFILE__

Like this:
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\file.jpg
```

And Finish!